# I am Not getting the second if statement .Even if I try to choose a card of my cards

Tags: python

```
import random
A = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13]
Shuffeled = random.sample(A,52)
print(Shuffeled)

print("")
PlayersCards = Shuffeled[:len(Shuffeled)//2]

ComputersCards = Shuffeled[len(Shuffeled)//2:]
print("Your Cards Are: "+str(PlayersCards))

a = input("Throw Your Card")
if 'a' not in PlayersCards:
  print("You don't have this card in your cards")
if 'a'in PlayersCards:
  print("Computer is playing.Please be patient")
```

Comment: `'a'` is the string `'a'`, not your variable `a`. Also you probably need to convert it to an int if it is supposed to be in that list of ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
typecast input(from str to int) that you take from user, like this
'if int(a) ______'

Answer (score 0):

several mistakes:

1. confused between string and int - you tried to find string in list of ints
2. you didn't convert the input to int at all

try this, after modifications:

```
import random
A = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13]
Shuffeled = random.sample(A,52)
print(Shuffeled)

print("")
PlayersCards = Shuffeled[:len(Shuffeled)//2]

ComputersCards = Shuffeled[len(Shuffeled)//2:]
print("Your Cards Are: "+str(PlayersCards))

a = int(input("Throw Your Card"))
if a not in PlayersCards:
  print("You don't have this card in your cards")
if a in PlayersCards:
  print("Computer is playing.Please be patient")
```

is that what you are looking for?